# What does += mean?

Tags: c, integer

I just had a quick question for all devs out there, what does `+=` mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a += b;
```

is equivalent to

```
a = a + b;
```

Likewise, you have `-=`, `*=`, `/=`, `%=`, `<<=`, `>>=`, `&=`, `|=` and `^=`.

But `<=` and `>=` mean "less or equal than" and "greater or equal than" respectively.

[This link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Reference_Tables#Table_of_Operators) should provide you with a comprehensive list of C operators.

Answer (score 2):

Uh..

```
X += Val
```

equivalent to

```
X = X + Val
```

Comment: In `x = x + val`, the expression `x` is evaluated twice, but in `x += val`, `x` is only evaluated once.  This can be important if `x` is a complex expression with side effects.

Answer (score 0):

```
a += b
```

Is the same as (shorthand for)

```
a = a + b
```

Similarly:

```
a++
```

and

```
++a
```

Are the same as (shorthand for)

```
a = a + 1
```

and

```
a += 1
```

Comment: a++ is not always the same as a += 1.

Comment: Agree with luiscubal, this is a very dangerous assumption.

Comment: Based on the sophistication of the original question, I don't think this is the place to have an in-depth discussion on pre/post increment

Comment: Yet you left the incorrect information in your post.

Comment: Because it is likely to be one of the next operators the poster sees.  It is not incorrect, it just doesn't include a 3 paragraph "fine print" for someone who clearly has never looked at C code before.